# Error when installing mariadb on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, perl, mariadb

I'm trying install wordpress locally on my chromebook following [these instructions](https://chromeready.com/4464/install-wordpress-chromebook/).

I successfully ran:
`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nano
```

`

But then get an error when I try to run
`

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
```

`

Here's the error from my terminal:
`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.32.0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`

I'm a complete newb at Linux and spend hours googling / trying solutions to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details, ie. what product & release of Ubuntu have you installed on your chromebook?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *I looked and no supported release of Ubuntu has the requirement you list in your paste, so you're not using Ubuntu or using an EOL release of Ubuntu*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know mariaDB is not compatible with ARM CPUs. I am assuming that your chromebook runs on ARM.